# How to compile and build C# projects with Ant and Mono?

Tags: c#, java, msbuild, ant, mono

I am currently working on a project with both java and C# codes within. Java takes the major role in this project. However, C# still takes a small part in it.

I am using Ant to build the projects, and would very much like to use it to build C# too. I have learned that it's possible to build C# under Ant with the help of Mono. Can anybody provide any link of tutorial or guidance here? I was trying to google for it. But I haven't found any comprehensive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ant to execute NAnt or MSBuild/XBuild to compile C# things is more suitable.

To be clear, `<exec>` task should be used to execute xbuild on Mono, or msbuild on Windows.

Comment: Do you happen to have any example?